# Surfaceview re-draw

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview

I have two images on a surfaceview and only one of the images is animated, the second image is static and keeps drawing itself over itself and so this makes the program slow. How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override draw in your SurfaceView and manually draw what you want.

Alex